# How to test for an empty vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure

What's the best way to test for an empty vector in Clojure? I expected that this would print false:

```
(if [] "true" "false")
```

but it doesn't. This does:

```
(if (> (count []) 0) "true" "false")
```

but is unwieldy - is there a shorter construct?

Comment: `[]` is the empty vector, not the empty list, isn't it?

Comment: @Svante yes. I suspect Kevin just wants to test for an empty collection in general, but is using a vector for his example while saying list.

Comment: You are correct; I edited the question. Running into a problem though, because people googling for "clojure test empty list" might want to find this question...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use standard predicate `(empty? list)`

Comment: Additionally you should use (seq list) when attempting to determine if the list is not empty.

Comment: Beware that one way or another you'll consider `nil` as a empty sequence. `(empty? nil) ; => true` and `(seq nil) ; => nil`. In few of my cases it wasn't desired behavior so I'd go with `#(and % (empty? %)` for testing whether something is "sequence and empty".

Answer (score 20):

The most common way I see in Clojure code to check for a non-empty list is to use [seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq). This returns nil if the collection is empty, or a valid seq object otherwise.

Example of usage:

```
(seq [])
=> nil

(seq nil)
=> nil

(seq [1 2 3])
=> (1 2 3)         ;; note this is a "true value"

(if (seq [1 4 6]) "true" "false")
=> "true"

(if (seq []) "true" "false")
=> "false"
```

You can also use [empty?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/empty_q) to test the opposite (i.e. test for an empty set). Note that empty? is implemented in the clojure source code as `(not (seq coll))` so you can be safe in the knowledge that the two approaches are fundamentally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mishadoff's answer (which is more readable), you could also compare against an empty list itself (and save two characters in length):

```
(if (= () []) "true" "false")
```

Hmmm... I still think I prefer Mishadoff's answer.

Comment: Just realized too that if zero evaluates to false, you could just use (count []). Still empty? is the way to go.

Comment: In clojure only `nil` and `false` constitute logical falsity. Zero is truthy.

Comment: This is not a good approach. nil is not equal to (), but it should be treated as an empty list.